# Where is the witchery spirit world inventory saved?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I just encountered a bug in witchery (i suppose) which made it such that on death, my inventory was not saved but put in a gravestone instead. It is a pain to get it back, plus it contains baubles that should have stayed in the overworld, but got put in the grave as well. I would like to try to transfer the gravestone content in the normal witchery inventory, but I can't find where it is saved. Please tell me in what NBT tag that inventory should.

Comment: You may have to go through the world save file (which is a pain to navigate) to find the block that the grave was in.

Comment: @ModDL That is clear. What is not clear is where to put said grave items, especially since I will need to put some of the items in the overworld inventory.

Comment: Not 100% sure but you can try finding another grave in the overworld and replacing the nbt tags of that